# Scala Doobie & Hikari CP transactor handling

Tags: scala, hikaricp, doobie

If you do this, HikariCP is init and shut down each time.
Is there any way to avoid this and execute various queries?

```
// Resource yielding a transactor configured with a bounded connect EC and an unbounded
// transaction EC. Everything will be closed and shut down cleanly after use.
  val transactor: Resource[IO, HikariTransactor[IO]] =
  for {
    ce <- ExecutionContexts.fixedThreadPool[IO](32) // our connect EC
    be <- Blocker[IO] // our blocking EC
    xa <- HikariTransactor.newHikariTransactor[IO](
      "org.h2.Driver", // driver classname
      "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", // connect URL
      "sa", // username
      "", // password
      ce, // await connection here
      be // execute JDBC operations here
    )
  } yield xa
```

run

```
transactor.use(sql"select 42".query[Int].unique.transact[IO]).unsafeRunSync()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you use `Resource`s in application.

You do do `.use` somewhere on `main` level, and then let your whole code requiring `Transactor` get that value passed, e.g:

```
val actorSystemResource: Resource[IO, ActorSystem]
val transactorResource: Resource[IO, Transactor[IO]]

// initialize controllers, services, etc and create routes for them
def routes(actorSystem: ActorSystem, transactor: Transactor[IO]): Route

val resources = for {
  transactor <- transactorResource
  actorSystem, <- actorSystemResource
  route = routes(actorSystem, transactor)
} yield (transactor, actorSystem, route)

resources.use { case (_, actorSystem, route) =>
  implicit system = actorSystem

  IO.fromFuture {
    Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `resource.allocated`, but it almost certainly would be a bad idea, resulting in a code that never runs the release part of the `Bracket` because it is easy to mess up and e.g. not calling it if some exception is thrown.